# Python : Redirecting device with MITM

Tags: python, scapy

I have built a MITM with python and scapy.I want to make the "victim" device be redirected to a specific page each time it tried to access a website. Any suggestions on how to do it?

*Keep in mind that all the traffic from the device already passes through my machine before being routed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly answer HTTP requests to pages different to that specific webpage with HTTP redirections (e.g. HTTP 302). Moreover, you should only route packets going to the desired webpage and block the rest (you can do so with a firewall such as iptables).